# Finding element and entering in Ruby Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I'm new to the Selenium and Ruby and Cucumber/Gherkins world and am trying a simple script to navigate to the Google page, find the search bar and enter a word and press enter or find the "Google Search" element and click.

This is in a Ruby file but formatted in Gherkins as I'm working with it.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

Given(/^I am on the Google website$/) do
  driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"
end

When(/^search is entered$/) do
  search = driver.find_element(xpath: "//div[@class = 'jhp big']//input[@class = 'gLFyf gsfi']")
  search.send_keys "this"
end

Then(/^confirm$/) do
  puts "Confirmed"
  driver.close
end
```

So here I'm navigating to the google website using a Selenium WebDriver initialized as driver. Then finding the element using the xpath and sending in the word 'this'.

When I run this, I get this error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class = 'jhp big']//input[@class = 'gLFyf gsfi']"}
```

Also, to click 'enter' I can either do send_keys :enter or find the Search button and use 'click' correct?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your XPath looks correct at a glance, other than maybe removing spaces in `@class = '`. You might need to also add a `wait` on the element XPath before you can attempt to locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use implicit wait for driver to wait until element found
Write the following code and then fit into your cucumber model

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to("https://www.google.com/")
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait=10
driver.find_element(name: 'q').send_keys 'raja'
driver.find_element(name: 'btnK').click
```

But remember, If you WATIR which is a wrapper around selenium binding these kind of waiting is automatic.

Comment: Got it, thank you. For clarification, what is the difference between using the manage.timeouts.implicit_wait and wait.until?

Comment: That's the bigger topic, but in short, wait.until is explicit wait which repeatedly call driver.find_element until it finds the element but you have to rescue inside the block when error happens but implicit_wait wouldn't happen at programming level, it happens at driver level, call to the driver.find_element happens only once and it internally waits until element found(or until timeout).